# divs Display property change via CSS media query

Tags: css, media-queries

trying to set different layout using media queries
i have truble with defining divs layout according to the screen width

this is [the fiddle result](http://jsfiddle.net/4v6FC/6/embedded/result/)

and
 [the fiddle test project](http://jsfiddle.net/4v6FC/6/) i am using

the problem is i would like it to get stack on top of others

```
red
green 
blue
```

when hitting less then 1200 px

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you are having is that CSS is ignoring your @media code. You are using inline CSS, and inline CSS rules always wins from external CSS rules (== your @media code).

recommend reading up on the cascading order of CSS: http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css

For your jsfiddle, transfer all code from the `style="..."` to your css frame on the right, making it external css instead of internal CSS. Then just reorder it like this: if you want media to override default css, place your @media selector **under** the code you want to be overridden.

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4v6FC/13/ 

There are a lot of ways you can use to stack the boxes vertically, if you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: that is right . now i had a little problem with the blue (the right one) getting under before intended and this was fixed now by reducing precentege of width to 28% each so now it is breaking line lyout only when intended

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/4v6FC/11/embedded/result/

I think you have a problem with css rules precedence: the `display` property defined in the style attribute of your `div` elements have more precedence than the one defined in your stylesheet, no matter the screen size.
For the example I just set this property for all `div` elements, outside the media query, and removed the `display` property from the style attribute.

Here is an article explaining cess rules precedence : http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:block` instead of `display:inline-block`  for class `Middle`

Comment: the idea was to have them side by side and then on resizing to <1200

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you have three containers who are taking the width and have `display:inline-block`. so they will be aligned parallel to each other. if you want this behavior, then you must warp them in a outer container and set its `min-width` to make it placed fixed in that position by specifying divs width in `px` rather than in `%`, [see here.](http://jsbin.com/inedaz/1/edit)

if you want elements to stack over each other then you must use `display:block`. in this case you don't need anything else.